# How can I pretty format JSON output in CakePHP?

Tags: json, cakephp

I would like my JSON output in CakePHP to be "pretty" or nicely formatted.
Right now, I call the `$javascript->object method` and my JSON is all on one line.

At times this can be difficult to see if there is a problem in the JSON output stream.

Answer (score 2):

You can preserve formatting with a html [`<pre>`](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block/pre.html) tag, which tells the browser that the text has been pre-formatted:

```
<pre><?php echo $javascript->object; ?></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

you might consider this: [Format JSON with PHP](http://recursive-design.com/blog/2008/03/11/format-json-with-php/)

and then `echo '<pre>'.indent(json_encode(your_array)).'</pre>';`

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 3.0+, you would use the _jsonOptions to set JSON_PRETTY_PRINT (along with any other json settings you would might need using a bitwise OR | operator)

```
$this->set('_jsonOptions', JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
$this->set(compact('myData'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['myData']);
```

Other json options you can set can be found here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php